# Can we embed CDATA inside the plain string of name value pair in an xml?

Tags: java, json, xml, cdata

I have a requirement to read Json from config xml with name value pair which has  CDATA.

My xml structure looks like below

```
<cfgsection name="test" value="<![CDATA[{Json data goes here}]]>"/>
```

I would like to know can CDATA be inside a plane string [""] since the documentation suggests that it should be inside a node/element?

Can any one shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDATA can only appear as part of element content, not as part of an attribute value. (It's easier to ask questions and understand the answers if you learn the correct terminology...)

That means you can write

```
<prop name="test"><![CDATA[{Some Json}]]></prop>
```

but you can't write

```
<prop name="test" value="<![CDATA[{Some Json}]]>"/>
```

CDATA, of course is just a device for escaping special characters, and there are other ways of escaping special characters in attributes. In fact, if you use single quotes around an attribute

```
<prop name="test" value='{"key":value, "data":[1,2,3]}'/>
```

then you usually won't need any escaping at all, unless your JSON data happens to contain strings with `"'"` or `"<"` in them -- in which case they can be written as XML character references.